# ОС не видит нормальный путь к файлу.

Tags: java, linux

Есть код:

```
package simple;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class Main {

public Main() {
    try {
        File file = new File("/home/user/NetBeansProjects/Simple/Hello.java");
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        System.out.println("--before--");

        Process process = runtime.exec("notepad " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        int waitFor = process.waitFor();
        if (waitFor != 0) {
            throw new Exception("");
        }

        System.out.println("--after--");

    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }       
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
}

}
```

При запуске открывает блокнот и пишет: "Файл **ome/user/NetBeansProjects/Simple/Hello.java"** не существует. При сохранении пишет что неверно указан путь. Что за муть? Почему "ome/user..." вместо "/home/user/..."? Будто ограничение какое то по длине есть. На винде всё нормально.

Система Linux: Ubuntu 11.10 + Openjdk_1.6 (из репозитория)
Система windows: seven + jdk1.7

Comment: А что за программа *notepad* в linux ? Это под wine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не уверен, но возможно "/h" вначале пути к файлу трактуется как параметр командной строки. попробуйте запускать так, чтобы в итоге команда имела вид:

```
notepad "/home/user/NetBeansProjects/Simple/Hello.java"
```

в коде:

```
"notepad \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Это загадка, но иногда требуется вставить двойной слэш вместо одинарного. Если честно никогда не разбирался толком почему и как, но это помогает. Читал множество дискуссий на эту тему [типа таких](https://superuser.com/questions/314102/what-causes-double-slashes-in-linux) - если интересно можете погуглить. Мне это неинтересно.

А самый верный способ это использовать строку `File.pathSeparator` в качестве разделителя в пути, а корень взять из метода `File.listRoots()`

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Сейчас попробую.